# EventSource disconnects after first message

Tags: php, http, server-sent-events

A bit confused about `EventSource` behavior.

It connects well and stays connected until it receives first message.

As i send a `data: something\n\n` message, the connection is dropped and new one created.

Using `Content-Type: text/event-stream` header and the connection are recognized as a event stream and the inspector shows `pending` status.

As i said, everything works well until i send first message.

After this the connection are interrupted and new one created and message not sent to browser(at least the page not updated as it should).

My server and client code are exactly as here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/

This happens on any browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure your server code are not sending `Transfer-Encoding` header.

Or if it sending it, make sure it is not set to chunked.

**`EventSource` behaves strange on chunked `Transfer-Encoding`**

You may remove `Transfer-Encoding` header or set it to `identity`.

If that does not help, make sure your web server does not set that header to chunked.

If it does and you can not update its config, make sure your code are setting the header to `identity`(headers set by your code will override ones set by web server).

If you simply remove the header in your code, the browser will use one set by web server,
so make sure to set it to `identity` rather than remove.

Comment: Doh! It works with identity transfer encoding! Why is not this documented anywhere? Thanks man!

Comment: well, it is documented [here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/comms.html#notes) :)

Comment: **beware!** - in PHP, if you define your keep-alive loop as `do{...}while(...)` then your connection will keep on re-connecting; even if you have no `exit` or `die` or any calls to such in your `do` and even if the `while` remains true. Yes it's weird and wrong and whatever, but I've spent 8 hours trying to figure out WTF is causing my client-side to re-connect after every 1st message from server ... changing to `while(1){...}` worked flawlessly. Hopes this helps someone.

Comment: .. and no i did NOT "miss" anything that caused the loop to end; only tested this on PHP7.3 though.