# Unusual EventSource error in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, server-sent-events

Unlike others, for me the EventSource is getting triggered and working fine in both Chrome and Firefox. But in Firefox whenever I receive a message in browser, I receive an error message along with it. Does not happen in Chrome.

Client code:

```
var source = new EventSource('***');
source.addEventListener('message', function(event) { 
    ...
}, false);
source.addEventListener('ping', function(e) {
    ...
}, false);

source.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
    ... // now this part gets executed in firefox, whenever i recieve a msg
}, false);
```

Server, nodejs code:

```
    ***.on('fin',function(message){
        delete ***;
        res.header('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
        res.write('data: '+JSON.stringify(message)+'\n\n');
        res.end();
    });
    ***.on('busError',function(){
        delete ***;
        res.send(500);
    });
```

Comment: Well, *what* error message do you get?

Comment: Can you add what Node.JS server module you are using? I've used 'http' and not hit this problem, but maybe I've just not stressed it enough? How large is your `message` string?

Comment: @bergi, the error message i get is empty, , the message is tiny, 100-200 characters, the curious thing was, the error does nothing, it just appears. But changing the 'Transport-encoding' to 'identity' fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the solution myself,

apparantly there is one important header, Transfer-Encoding - it should either be removed, or kept as identity, i guess in firefox, it is taken as chunks by default and that was causing the problem.

once i added the below line in server, error flew away.

`res.header('Transfer-Encoding', 'identity');`

my source the answer to another [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590755/eventsource-disconnects-after-first-message)  .

[documentation](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/comms.html#notes)